# preserve column order after converting to dataframe from dict

Tags: python, pandas

How do i preserve the dataframe column names same as lst dict without getting changed to alphabetical order?

Issue: the below code after getting dataframe shows column 'aa' first then 'no'

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
no = 0
for i in range(1,10):
    no = no + 1
    aa = "ab"
    lst = {'no':no,'aa':aa}
    df = df.append(lst,ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specified order in empty DataFrame first:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['no','aa'])
no = 0
for i in range(1,10):
    no = no + 1
    aa = "ab"
    lst = {'no':no,'aa':aa}
    df = df.append(lst,ignore_index=True)
    
print (df)
  no  aa
0  1  ab
1  2  ab
2  3  ab
3  4  ab
4  5  ab
5  6  ab
6  7  ab
7  8  ab
8  9  ab
```